# First Pong game

Tags: python, pygame

This is my first pygame project that I've worked on and wanted to start with something simple. Pong was, I think, a pretty good choice now that I'm done with it. I will continue to make improvements to the game and adjustments, but I would like the community to review and give suggestions for improvements. I'm a hobbyist and know next to nothing about computer science.

The improvements I had in mind for the next version would be changing the angle of the ball based on where on the paddle the ball hits and adding sound. I'm also going to work on a simple AI for single player.

I'm looking to see if my code is structured in a way that is not normal or is just bad by design. I'm interested to hear about using this style of coding for larger games and how it scales as the game gets bigger. Let me know what you think.

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()

screensize1 = 1500
screensize2 = 1000

win = pygame.display.set_mode((screensize1, screensize2))

pygame.display.set_caption('Test Environment')


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, score):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 20
        self.score = score
        self.up = False
        self.down = False


class Projectile(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, angle):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = 6
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.angle = angle
        self.vel = 20
        self.xvel = int(round((math.sin(math.radians(self.angle)) * self.vel), 0))
        self.yvel = int(round((math.cos(math.radians(self.angle)) * self.vel), 0))


def redraw_game_window():
    global Char2Win, Char1Win, s1_WaitToStart
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.line(win, (255, 0, 0), (screensize1//2, 0), (screensize1//2, screensize2), 4)
    if s1_WaitToStart is True:
        win.blit(pygame.font.SysFont('None', 50).render('Press Space To Start', 0, (255, 255, 255)), ((screensize1//2)-180, ((screensize2//2)-25)))
    if Char1Win is True:
        win.blit(pygame.font.SysFont('None', 50).render('Player 1 Wins', 0, (255, 255, 255)), ((screensize1//4)-160, ((screensize2//2)-25)))
        win.blit(pygame.font.SysFont('None', 50).render('Press Space To Start New Game', 0, (255, 255, 255)), ((screensize1//2)-200, ((screensize2//4 + screensize2//2)-25)))
    if Char2Win is True:
        win.blit(pygame.font.SysFont('None', 50).render('Player 2 Wins', 0, (255, 255, 255)), ((screensize1//4 + screensize1//2)-160, ((screensize2//2)-25)))
        win.blit(pygame.font.SysFont('None', 50).render('Press Space To Start New Game', 0, (255, 255, 255)), ((screensize1//2)-200, ((screensize2//4 + screensize2//2)-25)))
    win.blit(pygame.font.SysFont('None', 100).render(str(char1.score) + '     ' + str(char2.score), 0, (255, 255, 255)), ((screensize1//2)-85, 20))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, char1.color, (char1.x, char1.y, char1.width, char1.height))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, char2.color, (char2.x, char2.y, char2.width, char2.height))
    pygame.draw.circle(win, ball.color, (ball.x, ball.y), ball.radius)
    pygame.display.update()


char1 = Player((255, 0, 0), 25, (screensize2//2) - 90, 25, 160, 0)
char2 = Player((255, 0, 0), screensize1 - 50, (screensize2//2) - 90, 25, 160, 0)
ball = Projectile((screensize1//8) + (screensize1//4), screensize2//4, 315)

s1_WaitToStart = True
s2_BallAtPlayerOne = False
s3_PlayerTwoScore = False
s4_PlayerOneHit = False
s5_HitsWall = False
s6_BallAtPlayerTwo = False
s7_PlayerOneScore = False
s8_PlayerTwoHit = False

Char1Win = False
Char2Win = False
laststate = ''


run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and char1.y > char1.vel:
        char1.y -= char1.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and char1.y < screensize2 - char1.height - char1.vel:
        char1.y += char1.vel

    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and char2.y > char2.vel:
        char2.y -= char2.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and char2.y < screensize2 - char2.height - char2.vel:
        char2.y += char2.vel

# STATES OF GAME PLAY *************************************************************************************************

    if s1_WaitToStart is True:
        ball.x = (screensize1//8) + (screensize1//4)
        ball.y = screensize2//4
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            s2_BallAtPlayerOne = True
            s1_WaitToStart = False

    if s1_WaitToStart is False and s7_PlayerOneScore is False and s3_PlayerTwoScore is False and s4_PlayerOneHit is False and s8_PlayerTwoHit is False and s5_HitsWall is False:
        ball.x += ball.xvel
        ball.y += ball.yvel

    if s2_BallAtPlayerOne is True:
        ball.xvel = int(round((math.sin(math.radians(ball.angle)) * ball.vel), 0))
        ball.yvel = int(round((math.cos(math.radians(ball.angle)) * ball.vel), 0))
        if ball.x <= char1.x + char1.width:
            if char1.y - (2 * ball.radius) < ball.y or ball.y < char1.y + char1.height:
                s4_PlayerOneHit = True
                s2_BallAtPlayerOne = False
        if ball.x < char1.x + char1.width + ball.radius:
            if char1.y + char1.height + ball.radius <= ball.y or ball.y <= char1.y - ball.radius:
                s3_PlayerTwoScore = True
                s2_BallAtPlayerOne = False
        if ball.y >= screensize2 - (2 * ball.radius):
            if laststate != 's5':
                s5_HitsWall = True
                s2_BallAtPlayerOne = False
        if ball.y <= 0 + (2 * ball.radius):
            if laststate != 's5':
                s5_HitsWall = True
                s2_BallAtPlayerOne = False
        laststate = 's2'

    if s3_PlayerTwoScore is True:
        char2.score += 1
        if char2.score == 4:
            Char2Win = True
            s3_PlayerTwoScore = False
        ball.x = (screensize1 // 8) + (screensize1 // 2)
        ball.y = screensize2 // 4
        ball.angle = 315
        s2_BallAtPlayerOne = True
        s3_PlayerTwoScore = False
        laststate = 's3'

    if s4_PlayerOneHit is True:
        ball.xvel = 0
        ball.yvel = 0
        if 0 < ball.angle > 270:
            ball.angle -= 270
            ball.x += ball.xvel
            ball.y += ball.yvel
            s6_BallAtPlayerTwo = True
            s4_PlayerOneHit = False
        elif 270 > ball.angle > 180:
            ball.angle -= 90
            ball.x += ball.xvel
            ball.y += ball.yvel
            s6_BallAtPlayerTwo = True
            s4_PlayerOneHit = False
        laststate = 's4'

    if s5_HitsWall is True:
        ball.xvel = 0
        ball.yvel = 0
        if ball.y < screensize2//2:
            if 180 > ball.angle > 90:
                ball.angle -= 90
                s6_BallAtPlayerTwo = True
                s5_HitsWall = False
            else:
                ball.angle += 90
                s2_BallAtPlayerOne = True
                s5_HitsWall = False
        if ball.y > screensize2//2:
            if 0 < ball.angle < 90:
                ball.angle += 90
                s6_BallAtPlayerTwo = True
                s5_HitsWall = False
            else:
                ball.angle -= 90
                s2_BallAtPlayerOne = True
                s5_HitsWall = False
        laststate = 's5'

    if s6_BallAtPlayerTwo is True:
        ball.xvel = int(round((math.sin(math.radians(ball.angle)) * ball.vel), 0))
        ball.yvel = int(round((math.cos(math.radians(ball.angle)) * ball.vel), 0))
        if ball.x >= char2.x - (2 * ball.radius):
            if char2.y - (2 * ball.radius) < ball.y or ball.y < char2.y + char2.height + ball.y:
                s8_PlayerTwoHit = True
                s6_BallAtPlayerTwo = False
        if ball.x > char2.x - (2 * ball.radius):
            if char2.y + char2.height <= ball.y or ball.y <= char2.y - (2 * ball.radius):
                s7_PlayerOneScore = True
                s6_BallAtPlayerTwo = False
        if ball.y >= screensize2 - (2 * ball.radius):
            if laststate != 's5':
                s5_HitsWall = True
                s6_BallAtPlayerTwo = False
        if ball.y <= 0 + (2 * ball.radius):
            if laststate != 's5':
                s5_HitsWall = True
                s6_BallAtPlayerTwo = False
        laststate = 's6'

    if s7_PlayerOneScore is True:
        char1.score += 1
        if char1.score == 4:
            Char1Win = True
            s7_PlayerOneScore = False
        ball.x = (screensize1 // 8) + (screensize1 // 4)
        ball.y = screensize2 // 4
        ball.angle = 45
        s6_BallAtPlayerTwo = True
        s7_PlayerOneScore = False
        laststate = 's7'

    if s8_PlayerTwoHit is True:
        ball.xvel = 0
        ball.yvel = 0
        if 0 < ball.angle < 90:
            ball.angle += 270
            ball.x += ball.xvel
            ball.y += ball.yvel
            s2_BallAtPlayerOne = True
            s8_PlayerTwoHit = False
        elif 90 < ball.angle < 180:
            ball.angle += 90
            ball.x += ball.xvel
            ball.y += ball.yvel
            s2_BallAtPlayerOne = True
            s8_PlayerTwoHit = False
        laststate = 's8'

    if Char2Win is True:
        ball.xvel = 0
        ball.yvel = 0
        ball.x = (screensize1 // 8) + (screensize1 // 4)
        ball.y = screensize2 // 4
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            char2.score = 0
            char1.score = 0
            Char2Win = False
            s1_WaitToStart = True

    if Char1Win is True:
        ball.xvel = 0
        ball.yvel = 0
        ball.x = (screensize1 // 8) + (screensize1 // 4)
        ball.y = screensize2 // 4
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            char2.score = 0
            char1.score = 0
            Char1Win = False
            s1_WaitToStart = True

    redraw_game_window()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good start. Working from top to bottom here are some things I notice:

- Minimal imports is usually a good sign, just make sure you aren't doing unnecessary work because [Python is batteries included](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0206/#batteries-included-philosophy)
- Classes are a good way to organize things, but I would suggest that you add some default values to your initializers, and potentially some verification that values are valid (e.g. can `x`/`y`/`radius` be negative, etc.)
- `if s1_WaitToStart is True:` can just be `if s1_WaitToStart:` (this happens a lot in the code you provided)
- Global variables are (usually) bad. I would consider wrapping them in a `Config`  or `State` object
- I would wrap the `while run:` block in a [top-level environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)
- `# STATES OF GAME PLAY *************************************************************************************************` oof

At this point we've made it pretty far into your example and things are looking alright. But usually a long comment dividing up some code indicates that things are getting [smelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). I would think about how you keep track of the game's state with its own object, and refactor your ball mechanics into reusable functions. Really just breaking up the game logic loop that you have would make this more digestible to the reader, and closer to what someone with software engineering experience would expect. Adding comments is (usually) a good thing as well. To help you think about what behavior lends itself to good code, ask yourself if the code you're writing would scale to 2, 5, 10, 100+ users, and if you would be able to jump back into the block you're in the middle of after a month without looking at it.

Comment: Oh nice.  yeah the state objects idea could help a lot I think.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702168/python-define-a-state-object here is a different thread that talks about it a little bit.  The `STATES OF GAMEPLAY COMMENT` was part of my working notes that I forgot to delete.  I found myself scrolling back and forth a lot when working on the redraw function and just needed something to pop at my eye.  I'll have to read up on top level environments. It's not something I know anything about.  what would the benefit be?